# Create Gitlab Runner on linux locally

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci.yml

I have just started learning CI/CD and trying to implement locally. My code is hosted on gitlab and I have also configured .gitlab-ci.yml file correctly but my issue is I dont want to use gitlab managed shared runners. I want to create my own runner.
Now I actually dont know how to install gitlab runner locally on my linux development machine and then connect it to gitlab so that my pipelines start running. Right now my pipeline do trigger but because I have not configured any runner, it goes into stuck stage and eventually fail.
Sharing of particular commands would be highly appreciable. Thanks